# cmake ninja clang windows fails helloworld

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, ninja

Following the build directions from [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2016-April/063285.html), with the exception that I have newer versions of the tools.

cmake(3.6.1), ninja(1.7.1), vs-studio community 2015

```
clang version 3.8.1 (branches/release_3
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

I noted that the step `Detecting CXX compile features` fails. I included just the first of about 20 errors for brevity's sake.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(helloworld)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << "Hello World\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Open a VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

```
>> set PATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\msbuild-bin;%PATH%
>> set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\3.8.1\include;%INCLUDE%
>> cmake -G "Ninja" ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/griffic/src/helloworld/ninjabuild

>> ninja
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\MSBUIL~1\cl.exe   /nologo   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\ -c ..\main.cpp
In file included from ..\main.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\istream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocnum:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cmath:647:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h:8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtr1common(213,22) :  error: use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
        struct _Is_integral<char16_t>
                            ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtr1common(219,22) :  error: use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
        struct _Is_integral<char32_t>
```

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the 4.0 windows snapshot [here](http://llvm.org/builds/), which worked for me for helloworld. Unfortunately, it failed on a slightly larger test program which incorporates usage of [gtest](https://github.com/grifcj/cmake-gtest).

But instead of setting paths, I did the below to make helloworld function with the 4.0 snapshot.

Opened the VS2015 x64 Native Tools command prompt

```
>> set CC=clang-cl
>> set CXX=clang-cl
>> cmake -G "Ninja" ..
>> ninja
```